# Scala REPL Remove Dependency

Tags: scala, read-eval-print-loop

So I am using the Spark-Shell which is essentially the Scala REPL with added in dependencies and a few setup procedures. The problem with some of my code that I am running through it is there are already dependencies added in. I was wondering if there is a way to remove dependencies to add newer ones I want?

I can easily add in new ones with the :cp .jar command but it does not seem to be overwriting the one that is currently there.

Comment: Not really. `:reset` gives you a new compiler but I don't know offhand how it interacts with `:require`. Moreover you lose history. There's a ticket to make `:reset` more useful. Actually I see `:reset -classpath x.jar` ought to work in some form.

Answer (score 1):

You could try writing you own Spark-Shell which would give you fine grain control over your dependencies. Spark-Shell is essentially `sbt console` with a few [initialCommands](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/44c7c62bcfca74c82ffc4e3c53997fff47bfacac/project/SparkBuild.scala#L537-L559) in a `build.sbt`.